# Sort by High / Low

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to get the product on a catergory page to sort by high or low by using this code.

```
 <?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>">Low</a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>">High</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

The code works but I want the High and Low text to stay on the page. At the moment if you click high it disappears whens displaying high priced items and vice versa for low.

Just want to display High / Low when selecting either.

Thanks for any help,

Ben.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, you just have to add the other link in each **if** condition. It would be best to remove the link on current selected order, and only let the other one to be clickable, and also add a "selected" class to the selected one. This way you can highlight the current selection.

```
<?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>">Low</a>
    <span>/</span>
    <span class="selected">High</span>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="selected">Low</span>
    <span>/</span>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>">High</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you so much for that - it is working well but I have come across another issue with this.  The sort by drop down needs to be selected on Price  - Do you know how I could not have the dropdown and have it selected just on price - then your above code would work perfectly.  Thank you once again :)